# gams solve lst file is too large to be opened

Tags: gams-math

The model size of my GAMS model is too large. It can be solved, but the solve.lst file is too large to be opened. I need open it to check some results. Are there anyone meet this problems before? Please give me some ideas/hints to fix it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your model text is very large you can use

```
$Offlisting
```

to surpress most outputs.

```
$Offsymlist
```

will get rid of symbol listing.

```
$Offinclude
```

will prevent include file printing.
Sometimes the number of equations explicitly printed is set too high (esp. when chaining multiple solve statements with loops etc). You can set the number of listed equations per block to zero with this option:

```
option limrow=0;
```

Similarly

```
option limcol=0;
```

will set the number of variables explicitly displayed in the listing to zero.